# PHP Warning: GearmanClient::doBackground(): gearman_connection_flush:write:111

Tags: php, virtual-machine, vagrant, gearman

I am trying to replicate our production setup using Vagrant on my Mac to see if I can replicate a problem we are having running multiple Gearman servers.

However, I am unable to get the "web" virtual machine to send jobs to the Gearman queues, getting instead the error described in the subject.  I can ping between the two VMs and I can SSH from one VM to the other, but it seems I am unable to establish a telnet connection on port 4730.

I have started the Gearman server from the CLI (with -vvv) to see if I could see more of that is going on, and I can see that the backend is actually accepting a connection from the web VM, as follows:

```
INFO Starting up
INFO Listening on 0.0.0.0:4730 (6)
INFO Creating wakeup pipe
INFO Creating IO thread wakeup pipe
INFO Adding event for listening socket (6)
INFO Adding event for wakeup pipe
INFO Entering main event loop
INFO Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:48217
INFO [   0]       127.0.0.1:48217 Connected
INFO Accepted connection from 33.33.33.11:48208
INFO [   0]     33.33.33.11:48208 Connected
INFO [   0]     33.33.33.11:48208 Disconnected
INFO Accepted connection from 33.33.33.12:34402
INFO [   0]     33.33.33.12:34402 Connected
INFO [   0]     33.33.33.12:34402 Disconnected
INFO Accepted connection from 33.33.33.12:34404
INFO [   0]     33.33.33.12:34404 Connected
INFO [   0]     33.33.33.12:34404 Disconnected
INFO Accepted connection from 33.33.33.12:34406
INFO [   0]     33.33.33.12:34406 Connected
INFO [   0]     33.33.33.12:34406 Disconnected
```

However, it does not seem to be doing anything with the connection that it receives.  Does anyone else have any experience of this issue, or can maybe shed some light into what error 111 is?

Thanks.

Comment: I have somewhat similar issue. But it happens sometimes 4-6 times per day. I get this PHP warning (110 instead 111) gearman_connection_flush:write:110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you bound the gearman to only accept connections from localhost? As I can see the other connections 33.33.33.11-12 disconnecting but local host is staying up.

I only get that error when it can't connect to a gearman job server.

What is your gearman start up command?

Comment: I was told that setting it to listen on 0.0.0.0 meant it would listen on any interface, and so that is what I specify.  Anyway, this problem went away through other means (we used a different VM setup) so I will accept this answer as it seems the most likely problem :o)